mkShell is not a function
install nodejs mongodb and mongosh using a flake, and since mongosh is considered unfree software i added the last line
{
  description = "Installing Nodejs with a flake";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs-stable.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-23.11";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs-stable, ... }: with nixpkgs-stable.legacyPackages.x86_64-linux; {
    devShells.x86_64-linux.TestingNodejsFlake = mkShell {
      buildInputs = [
        nodejs
        mongodb
        mongosh
      ];
    }
     { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
             "mongodb"
           ];
     };
  };
}

and i ran nix develop and i got this error:
error: error: attempt to call something which is not a function but a set

       at /nix/store/q0wkasbrmwk8zyz719g4c0gb6d58v1j7-source/flake.nix:9:49:

            8|   outputs = { self, nixpkgs-stable, ... }: with nixpkgs-stable.legacyPackages.x86_64-linux; {
            9|     devShells.x86_64-linux.TestingNodejsFlake = mkShell {
             |                                                 ^
           10|       buildInputs = [

well i'm trying to develop a web app using a flake , that's all

Consider using flake-utils, and ditch with.

("Consider using flake-utils" in part because that'll let you make your flake architecture- and OS-independent, vs hardcoding x86_64-linux)

config should be passed as an argument to nixpkgs when it's being instantiated.
{
  description = "Installing Nodejs with a flake";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs-stable.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-23.11";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { nixpkgs-stable, flake-utils, ... }: flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
    let
      inherit (nixpkgs-stable) lib;
      pkgs = import nixpkgs-stable {
        inherit system;
        config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
          "mongodb"
        ];
      };
    in {
      devShells.TestingNodejsFlake = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = [
          pkgs.nodejs
          pkgs.mongodb
          pkgs.mongosh
        ];
      };
    });
}


It worked :D, I'm super grateful, but I really wanna know how you learned all the options in the Nix language. it's overwhelming with little to no resources

Dude, your flake breaks my whole pc, it becomes so laggy, that it can't even stop the process, what is this code doing lol?

Sounds like you don't have enough RAM to run the build. Works fine for me, but I have 32gb handy.

I'm gonna use the community cache then, thx for your service :D
